# Overwriting Ubuntu 11.04 with 14.04 LTS while keeping windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, wubi

I am trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want it to overwrite the currently installed Ubuntu 11.04 and leave Windows 7 untouched.

I have four drives (C,E,F,R) on windows. Is there a sure fire way to map which drive belongs to which partition while installing ubuntu aside from guessing based on the size of the partition?

While attempting to install ubuntu 14.04 it seemed like it was going to install it on the same drive as my older ubuntu but was not touching the used space, though it provided me with an option to re-size it.

What's the best approach here? Do I have to delete the older ubuntu before trying to use that space for writing a newer version or will re-sizing the partition during new install do the trick? How do I delete the old Ubuntu? Is uninstalling Wubi enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up a terminal from the Live USB and type

```
blkid
```

This will show you partition info. Here's the output on mine:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="<removed>" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="<removed>"
/dev/sda2: UUID="<removed>" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="<removed>"
/dev/sda3: UUID="<removed>" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="<removed>"
/dev/sda4: UUID="<removed>" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="<removed>"
```

`NTFS` partitions are Windows'. See which partition are Ubuntu's and install.